# Upgrade SQL Server Server Express to Licensed Enterpise edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-express, enterprise-edition

we have sql server express edition 2017 with default instanc ,now we want to upgrade it to Enterprise Licensed Edition 2017 with default instance in the same server

At first I thought I had to uninstall express edition but after some search found out that we can upgrade editions

What I want

> After upgrade will 10GB DB limit in express editon will be gone and apply the Enterprise Edition ?

> everything will work  as before but with new capabilities of Enterprise edition ?

Kindly clear my query ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> After upgrade will 10GB DB limit in express editon will be gone and apply the Enterprise Edition ?

Yes.

> everything will work as before but with new capabilities of Enterprise edition ?

Pretty much. But ideally you should test with a non-production instance first, that you can apply a similar workload to as your production instance.

Any major changes (whether it be version upgrades or edition upgrades) can result in performance regressions for some queries. Enterprise Edition has a lot of features meant to improve query performance, but those significant changes can theoretically impact a query in a negative way, that was working fine previously.